# Определить нажатие на левой или правой части элемента пути SVG (компонент React)

Tags: html, svg, события

У меня есть компонент svg, у которого есть обработчик `onClick`.
Как я могу определить, какая часть этого `path` была нажата?
Мой path - полукруг, и мне нужно определить часть, по которой щелкнули (слева 1/2 или справа - 1/2)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 651 592" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M636.971 285C636.971 322.427 628.927 359.487 613.298 394.065C597.668 428.643 574.76 460.061 545.881 486.525C517.002 512.99 482.718 533.983 444.986 548.306C407.253 562.628 366.812 570 325.971 570C285.13 570 244.689 562.628 206.957 548.306C169.224 533.983 134.94 512.99 106.061 486.525C77.1818 460.061 54.2737 428.643 38.6445 394.065C23.0153 359.487 14.9711 322.427 14.9711 285H110.253C110.253 310.96 115.833 336.666 126.674 360.65C137.515 384.634 153.404 406.427 173.435 424.783C193.467 443.14 217.247 457.701 243.419 467.636C269.591 477.57 297.643 482.684 325.971 482.684C354.3 482.684 382.351 477.57 408.523 467.636C434.695 457.701 458.475 443.14 478.507 424.783C498.538 406.427 514.428 384.634 525.268 360.65C536.109 336.666 541.689 310.96 541.689 285H636.971Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Detect left or right part was clicked of the path element of SVG (React component)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68997678/7394871) от участника  [@Drem Edys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13354938/drem-edys).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68997678/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто при клике на фигуру проверить координаты клика (`clientX`) и сравнить их с серединой фигуры (`rect.x + rect.width/2`). Габариты и положение фигуры получаем при каждом клике методом `path.getBoundingClientRect()`.

```js
const path = document.querySelector('path');

path.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let rect = path.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(e.clientX < rect.x + rect.width/2){
        text.textContent = "LEFT SIDE";
    } else if(e.clientX > rect.x + rect.width/2){
        text.textContent = "RIGHT SIDE";
    } else {
        text.textContent = "CENTER!!!";
    }
})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 200 651 400" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M636.971 285C636.971 322.427 628.927 359.487 613.298 394.065C597.668 428.643 574.76 460.061 545.881 486.525C517.002 512.99 482.718 533.983 444.986 548.306C407.253 562.628 366.812 570 325.971 570C285.13 570 244.689 562.628 206.957 548.306C169.224 533.983 134.94 512.99 106.061 486.525C77.1818 460.061 54.2737 428.643 38.6445 394.065C23.0153 359.487 14.9711 322.427 14.9711 285H110.253C110.253 310.96 115.833 336.666 126.674 360.65C137.515 384.634 153.404 406.427 173.435 424.783C193.467 443.14 217.247 457.701 243.419 467.636C269.591 477.57 297.643 482.684 325.971 482.684C354.3 482.684 382.351 477.57 408.523 467.636C434.695 457.701 458.475 443.14 478.507 424.783C498.538 406.427 514.428 384.634 525.268 360.65C536.109 336.666 541.689 310.96 541.689 285H636.971Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
<p id="text" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;font-size:30px">
    NO CLICK YET
</p>
```

По сути можно упростить условие до `e.offsetX < rect.width/2`, что более явно отражает ваши намерения.

Comment: Я не стал делать >= или <= для какой-нибудь из сторон, а добавил попадание по центру, но у меня совсем не получается в него попасть.

Comment: да..в вашем случае нету этого соединения  ... плюс поставил

Comment: Нет разъединения и нет соединения))) Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Основная идея:

1. Поместите фигуру в `<defs>`
2. нарисуйте   прямоугольники (r1 и r2) над каждой половиной.
3. используйте этот прямоугольник, чтобы построить 2 обтравочных контура (cp1 и cp2)
4. используйте фигуру дважды с помощью `<use>` и вырежите первую с помощью `cp1`,
   а вторую - с помощью `cp2`.
5. добавить слушателей событий к обрезанным элементам использования

```js
u1.addEventListener("click",()=>{console.log(u1.id)})
u2.addEventListener("click",()=>{console.log(u2.id)})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 200 651 392" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <path id="shape" d="M636.971 285C636.971 322.427 628.927 359.487 613.298 394.065C597.668 428.643 574.76 460.061 545.881 486.525C517.002 512.99 482.718 533.983 444.986 548.306C407.253 562.628 366.812 570 325.971 570C285.13 570 244.689 562.628 206.957 548.306C169.224 533.983 134.94 512.99 106.061 486.525C77.1818 460.061 54.2737 428.643 38.6445 394.065C23.0153 359.487 14.9711 322.427 14.9711 285H110.253C110.253 310.96 115.833 336.666 126.674 360.65C137.515 384.634 153.404 406.427 173.435 424.783C193.467 443.14 217.247 457.701 243.419 467.636C269.591 477.57 297.643 482.684 325.971 482.684C354.3 482.684 382.351 477.57 408.523 467.636C434.695 457.701 458.475 443.14 478.507 424.783C498.538 406.427 514.428 384.634 525.268 360.65C536.109 336.666 541.689 310.96 541.689 285H636.971Z" fill="red" />
<clipPath id="cp1">
    <rect id="r1" x="14.971099853515625" y="285" width="312" height="285"></rect>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="cp2">
    <rect id="r2" x="325.9710388183594" y="285" width="310.99993896484375" height="285"></rect>
</clipPath>
 </defs>
  
    <use xlink:href="#shape" clip-path="url(#cp1)" id="u1"/>
    <use xlink:href="#shape" clip-path="url(#cp2)" id="u2"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999593/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Comment: Привет Саша, там есть неприятность  то есть видно стык между первым rect и вторым rect в твоём ответе ... как это устрвнить безболезненно ? Ведь его нету в самом вопросе

Comment: @Айболит, он просто любезно оставил мне возможность дать более правильный ответ))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta - этот enxaneta "редиска", и ответы его... Вот пример, где меня побрили))): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68959953/12656388 нехорошие люди. Короче, никак не могу поставить плюсик этому Энкзанете)), хоть и в переводе.

Comment: @Leonid я там тоже тебя плюсанул

Comment: @Айболит я думаю, что автор специально оставил вертикальный зазор между половинками, чтобы было видно, где кликаешь. Зазор убрать нетрудно - сделать левую половину немного шире

Comment: плюс поставил -

Comment: там кстати на enSO есть шикарный вопрос ... сложный  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69104876/6339052

Comment: @Leonid почему ты считаешь, что тебя побрили, тебе же не наставили минусов? Просто никто плюс не поставил за сильный ответ. Это там обычное явление. Кстати на мой взгляд, enxaneta оч. сильный отвечающий и если надо, то и в canvas отлично отвечает.

Comment: Обошли вниманием - и есть побрили в данном случае. И так мы с ним несколько раз встречались и он ничего не отмечает плюсами. Тогда как я всегда других отвечающих на те же вопросы отмечаю ибо в теме и могу оценить ответ. Это детский сад, в общем то)) Просто захотелось плюсиков за вопрос, над которым трудился))) Спасибо, что поняли))

Comment: @Leonid ты посмотри его профиль, ни одного минуса не поставил. Это большая редкость и почти 3.000 плюсов отдал  И учти, у пользователей enSO, совершенно другая психология, оч. жёсткая конкуренция и enxaneta по сравнению с другими, просто ангел

Comment: Учту, только не пойму мотивации этой конкуренции. Что они там делят... У меня другое впечатление сложилось, там как-то подводят больше подправить ответ, минусов не ставят. А худшее - игнор, отсутствие обратной связи. И сейчас что здесь, что там - полнейший игнор всех и вся.

Comment: @Leonid Ты действительно считаешь, что там минусов не ставят? У меня другое впечатление У сильных отвечающих, например, как Temani соотношение плюсов и минусов 1 к 5  - 24,657 down

Comment: Ставят, конечно, я же везде где нашел этому enxaneta поставил минусов))) Я только по своим ответам сужу. Даже когда я не понимал суть отвечал вначале, то мало когда минусы хватал, больше в комментариях намекали на подумать над ответом. И опять же только личные впечатления от происходящего сейчас. Не знаю как в общем. Еще минусы я ставлю после того, как несколько дней не подправляют явно неправильный ответ, когда я в комментариях тоже намекаю))